# does not login at the first attempt

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have got a unique issue, i had put this script on body onload

`<body onload="document.getElementById('User_Email').focus();">`

this script will automatically place the mouse cursor in email text field when the page is loaded...but the problem iam facing now is...sometimes once we enter the username and password for the first time and after we  click on login button ,cursor will move back to username textbox by removing the password,and if we enter the username and password for the second time it works fine...

i dont know why its happening,bcos it does not happen all the time .have any of you guys faced the same problem....

any solution for this???

Comment: Do you have a demo or a link to your site if it's live?

Comment: May be your page is not loaded completely, try placing your code in  `$(document).ready(function(){....});`  in the head.

Comment: iam using local host ..k let me put the entire php script iam using ....`<body onload="document.getElementById('User_Email').focus();">
<form class="form_settings" name="Login" action="Talent_UserSetUp.php" Method="Post">
<label class="loginlabel">User Email</label> <br />
<?php
echo('<input type="text" name="User_Email" id="User_Email" value="'.$result1.'" >');
?>
<label class="loginlabel">Password</label> <br />
<input type="password" name="User_Password" id="Password">      
<br>
<input class="Medbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> `

Comment: remove script from body tag and try placing `<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
document.getElementById('User_Email').focus();
}); </script>` in your `<head>` tag

Comment: hello kakarott,now its working fine but as i have mentioned above iam not sure when it again... let me wait and see for 24 hours .....if it wroks fine with no error messages... i will very thankfull to you....

Comment: ok can i post this as answer?

Comment: @kakarott: sorry for stealing your thunder ;-P... to OP: If kakarott posts his answer, accept his, since he commented before I posted the answer. If you want to check, just hard-refresh, or open a private browsing window, it doesn't cache JS, so nothing of the browser cache can interfere with the result. If it works in private/incognito (_aka porn-mode_), it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `onload="document.getElementById('User_Email').focus();"`

Fom `<body>` tag

And add

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#User_Email').focus();
});
```

In your `<head>` tag.

Comment: +1 to you, Goku ;) An even simpler code would be: `$(function(){..})`

Answer (score 1):

I'm with kakarott, your tags suggest you're using jQuery. Since it's custom to wrap all jQuery code in a `ready` callback function anyways, why not use that functionality, and leave that hideous in-line JS back in the 1990's, where it belongs?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#User_Email').focus();
});
```

Should work just fine. Line-per-line, this code does little more than:

> If *document*-object is loaded, call an anonymous function that sets the focus to the `$('#User_Email')` element.

Comment: @kakarott: Was just typing an apologetic comment :)